# Convertir imagen .jpeg a .pdf con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, pdf

Tengo un formulario en donde puedo subir un archivo y renombrar ese archivo, normalmente se suben archivos .**jpeg** pero necesitaría **convertirlos** en .**PDF**,  habría alguna manera de hacerlo fácil con PHP?

Os dejo el código donde se sube y se renombra el archivo

```
<?php 
    $target_path = "albaranes/";
    $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];
    $tipo_archivo = explode("/", $tipo_archivo);
    $tipo_archivo= '.'.$tipo_archivo[1];
    $nombre_archivo= $_POST['albaran'].$tipo_archivo;
    $target_path = $target_path.$nombre_archivo;

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            window.location='redireccionar.php';
            </script>";
    } 
     else{
        echo $target_path;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Has podido solucionarlo @Tefef ?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el módulo Imagick para convertir una imagen al formato que desees. Una vez tienes lo necesario puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$img = new Imagick('path/to/image.jpg');
$img->setImageFormat('pdf');
$success = $img->writeImage('path/to/image.pdf');
```

O

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($imageBytes);
$img->setImageFormat('pdf');
$success = $img->writeImage('path/to/image.pdf');
```

[Manual Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php)

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081459/upload-jpg-png-convert-to-pdf-and-save-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Para insertar una o varias imágenes dentro de un PDF puede utilizarse la librería **FPDF**

##### Convertir o insertar imagen (PNG, JPG o GIF) en PDF

Los valores que pasamos por parámetro son los siguientes:

```
Image(string file [, float x [, float y [, float w [, float h [, string type [, mixed link]]]]]])
```

Primero hay que descargar la librería **FPDF** completa oficial (http://www.fpdf.org/) y descomprimirla en el servidor.

Podemos encontrar toda al documentación sobre `Image()` en el sitio oficial de la librería: http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/image.htm

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);

// Insertara el logo en la parte top izquierda a -300 dpi
$pdf->Image('obelisco-1.jpg',10,10,-300);

// Imagen central
$pdf->Image('obelisco-2.jpg',60,30,90,0,'JPEG');
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

**Formato de la imagen.** Los posibles valores son (indiferente a mayúsculas): JPG, JPEG, PNG y GIF. Si no se especifica, el tipo se deduce de la extensión del fichero.

El PDF generado es el siguiente:

La imagen ionsertada en logo y la central. El tamaño utilizado fue el mismo pero en los parametros colocamos los valores deseados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

De hecho sí, puedes utilizar **Imagick** para convertir la imagen en el formato que desees, en tu caso a pdf.

```html
<?php 
    //$target_path = $target_path.$nombre_archivo;
    // -- Puedes verificar que sea solo para las imagenes
    $extIMG = "/^(jpg|jpeg)$/i";
    if (!preg_match($extIMG, $tipo_archivo)) {
        $nombre_archivo = $_POST['albaran'].".pdf";
        //-- Lo puedes trabajar con la ruta temporal
        $pdf = new Imagick($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);
        $pdf->setImageFormat('pdf');
        if ($pdf->writeImage($target_path.$nombre_archivo)) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                      window.location='redireccionar.php';
                  </script>";
        } else {
            echo $target_path.$nombre_archivo;
        }
    } else { //-- Continua como lo tenias anteriormente
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) { 
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                      window.location='redireccionar.php';
                  </script>";
        } else {
            echo $target_path.$nombre_archivo;
        }
    }
    
?>
```